# How to add image carousel in flutter

Tags: flutter, carousel

I am getting images from the firebase realtime database to the application with tag-imgPath. How can I give the images a carousel at the left and right ends of the fullscreen page so the user can go to next image without going back to the list of images and open another image on fullscreen.

```
class FullScreenImagePage extends StatelessWidget {
  String imgPath;
  FullScreenImagePage(this.imgPath);

  final LinearGradient backgroundGradient = new LinearGradient(
      colors: [new Color(0x10000000), new Color(0x30000000)],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new SizedBox.expand(
        child: new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(gradient: backgroundGradient),
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: new Hero(
                  tag: imgPath,
                  child: new Image.network(imgPath),
                ),
              ),
             ],

          ),
        ),


      ),

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clear, you are trying to display you images with carousel 
please use this package https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

[image]

full example code

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];

void main() => runApp(CarouselDemo());

final Widget placeholder = Container(color: Colors.grey);

final List child = map<Widget>(
  imgList,
  (index, i) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0), Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                'No. $index image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
).toList();

List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
  List<T> result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

class CarouselWithIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarouselWithIndicatorState createState() => _CarouselWithIndicatorState();
}

class _CarouselWithIndicatorState extends State<CarouselWithIndicator> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: true,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: map<Widget>(
          imgList,
          (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class CarouselDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Manually operated Carousel
    final CarouselSlider manualCarouselDemo = CarouselSlider(
      items: child,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
    );

    //Auto playing carousel
    final CarouselSlider autoPlayDemo = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      items: imgList.map(
        (url) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 1000.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );

    //Button controlled carousel
    Widget buttonDemo() {
      final basicSlider = CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        viewportFraction: 0.9,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
      );
      return Column(children: [
        basicSlider,
        Row(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => basicSlider.previousPage(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
                child: Text('prev slider'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => basicSlider.nextPage(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
                child: Text('next slider'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ]);
    }

    //Pages covers entire carousel
    final CarouselSlider coverScreenExample = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 1.0,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: false,
      items: map<Widget>(
        imgList,
        (index, i) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(i), fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    //User input pauses carousels automatic playback
    final CarouselSlider touchDetectionDemo = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 3),
      items: imgList.map(
        (url) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 1000.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );

    //Non-looping manual Carousel
    final CarouselSlider nonLoopingCarousel = CarouselSlider(
      items: child,
      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
    );

    //Vertical carousel
    final CarouselSlider verticalScrollCarousel = CarouselSlider(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 3),
      items: imgList.map(
        (url) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 1000.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );

    //create full screen Carousel with context
    CarouselSlider getFullScreenCarousel(BuildContext mediaContext) {
      return CarouselSlider(
        autoPlay: true,
        viewportFraction: 1.0,
        aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(mediaContext).size.aspectRatio,
        items: imgList.map(
          (url) {
            return Container(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0.0)),
                child: Image.network(
                  url,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 1000.0,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      );
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Carousel slider demo')),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Manuell Carousel'),
                  manualCarouselDemo,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Auto Playing Carousel'),
                  autoPlayDemo,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Button Controlled Carousel'),
                  buttonDemo(),
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Full Screen Carousel'),
                  coverScreenExample,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Carousel With Indecator'),
                  CarouselWithIndicator(),
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Pause When Touched Carousel'),
                  touchDetectionDemo,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('No infinity scroll carousel'),
                  nonLoopingCarousel,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Vertical scroll carousel'),
                  verticalScrollCarousel,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                //Builder needed to provide mediaQuery context from material app
                child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                  return Column(children: [
                    Text('Full screen carousel'),
                    getFullScreenCarousel(context),
                  ]);
                })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but for future references

```
 Carousel( dotSize: 3,  dotColor: Colors.black,  dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,  autoplay: false,  showIndicator: true,  images: [
           Image.network(widget.product_detail_picture,fit:BoxFit.fill,),     
      ],)
```

The one which says widget.product_detail_picture I have already initialized in my firebase storage code